# application define or object defined error in vba at vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help in resolving the below code. I am not able to get the vlookup value from another sheet, its giving error always "application define or object defined error"

```
For i = 1 To lrr
If Range("D" & i).Value = "" Then 'if cell in A is empty

On Error GoTo 0

Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-1], ('C:\Macros\[Consolidated BTG with Search Terms.xlsx]AU'!B:D),3,0)"
                                                 OR (with Sheet name by user input)
Range("D" & i).Formula = "=VLookup(RC[-1], Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range('B:D'), 3, 0)"

End If
```

i am trying to get values for a specific value if its empty and then vlookup from another sheet and past as special (values). I am stuck here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing A1 and R1C1 references. Choose one and make sure all the references use it.

So, Either:

```
Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-1], ('C:\Macros\[Consolidated BTG with Search Terms.xlsx]AU'!C2:C4),3,0)"
```

Or:

```
Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-1]," & Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range("B:D").Address(1,1,xlR1C1,1) & ", 3, 0)"
```

Comment: Thanks so much Scott, It worked perfectly what i was thinking.